# WPF - SearchBox based on editable ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have a search box based on ComboBox that allows users to choose one of the items in a big collection.

Classic ComboBox with **IsTextSearchEnabled="true"** is almost OK for me, but there are some problems.

1. DataBase has about 5000+ entries, so when the listbox of combobox is trying to show me all of the entries, program starts lagging. Thats why i want to show only some of the entries. And i dont want to see anything until users inputs at least 3 chars.

Idea is:

```
if (searchBox.Text.Length < 3) return;
else show only 10 (or less) entries starts with searchBox.Text.
```

2. Another problem is that i need listbox to be opened automatically when user typed in 3+ symbols. Changing **IsDropDownOpen** from code causes errors in ComboBox behaviour  (like it is just not working or when I type 2nd char 1st disappears).

All in all it should be something like google search bar.

And at the end I can't use any third-party packages or dll's for this program.

Comment: IsTextSearchEnabled is always enabled. You must set IsEditable to true to enable input based text search.

Comment: Next time please show the faulty code so that we can review it...

Comment: If I want to input the text in ComboBox then IsEditable is obviously == true. Sorry for not sharing any code and thx for your answer. I'll try it on monday.

Answer (score 0):

1. This feature is called UI virtualization and is already implemented. But while this feature is enabled for the `ListBox` by default, you must explicitly enable UI virtualization for the `ComboBox` (and other `ItemsControl` subtypes like the `TreeView`). This enables the control to load only the items that are visible.
   Generally, UI virtualization requires a `ScrollViewer` and a `VirtualizationPanel`. To enable UI virtualization for the `ComboBox`, you only have to replace the default `Panel` that hosts the items (which is a `StackPanel` by default). `ComboBox` already contains a `ScrollViewer` to host its content:

```xml
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

2. The `ComboBox` is a quite complex control. To change its behavior I generally recommend to extend the control to create a custom `ComboBox`. Appart from `ComboBox.IsEditable`, you should also set `ComboBox.StaysOpenOnEdit` to `true`.
   The following example gives you an example how to implement a solution that opens the drop-down after the third character was entered:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
          PreviewTextInput="OnComboBoxPreviewTextInput"
          LostFocus="OnComboBoxLostFocus" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
private StringBuilder SearchInput { get; } = new StringBuilder();
private const int ThresholdInputTextLength = 3;

private void OnComboBoxPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
  var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
  if (comboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
  {
    return;
  }

  this.SearchInput.Append(e.Text);
  if (this.SearchInput.Length >= ThresholdInputTextLength)
  {
    if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(comboBox, "PART_EditableTextBox", out TextBox editTextBox))
    {
      var currentSuggestion = editTextBox.Text;
      comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
      Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
      {
        editTextBox.Text = currentSuggestion;
        int selectionStartIndex = this.SearchInput.Length;
        int selectionLength = currentSuggestion.Length - this.SearchInput.Length;
        editTextBox.Select(selectionStartIndex, selectionLength);
        this.SearchInput.Clear();
      }, DispatcherPriority.Input);
    }
  }
}

private void OnComboBoxLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
  => this.SearchInput.Clear();

public static bool TryFindVisualChildElementByName<TChild>(
  DependencyObject parent,
  string childElementName,
  out TChild resultElement) where TChild : FrameworkElement
{
  resultElement = null;

  if (parent is Popup popup)
  {
    parent = popup.Child;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);

    if (childElement is TChild frameworkElement)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(childElementName) || frameworkElement.Name.Equals(
        childElementName,
        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        resultElement = frameworkElement;
        return true;
      }
    }

    if (TryFindVisualChildElementByName(childElement, childElementName, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thx 4 answer! 1st problem is completely solved - no more laggs.
But 2nd is not. When i type 2 letters comboBox makes suggestions according to my input. When i type 3rd, there is no more suggestions. And when i type 4th i have them again.

Comment: I have updated the example.